# Spawning Actors of class type?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to write a spawn function that accepts and spawns any Actor class. Here's what I have:

```
object entities {
    val system = ActorSystem("Entities")

    def spawnEntity(entity : Actor) = {
        system.actorOf(Props[entity])
}
```

Here it's saying it doesn't know what type entity is, which is understandable. However, I've also tried `classOf(entity)` and `entity.class` and that didn't work either.

How can I spawn an Actors like this? Desire functionality would be something like:

```
entities.spawnEntity(Bird)
entities.spawnEntity(Rabbit( /* params here * /)
```

Where Bird and Rabbit are Actors.

EDIT: Consider Bird and Rabbit's as objects, not classes. My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

`Props` requires a `Class` or a `ClassTag` in order to create the `Actor`, but `entity` is supposed to be an instance of an `Actor` (as the code is currently written). What you *want* is is the signature `entity: Class[_ <: Actor]`.

*Or*, you can use a type parameter instead, which is what you're trying to use in the implementation of `spawnEntity`.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def spawnEntity[Entity <: Actor: ClassTag] = system.actorOf(Props[Entity])
```

`spawnEntity` is now a parameterless method with one type parameter called `Entity`, which must be a sub-type (or the same type, bounded above) of `Actor`, where a `ClassTag[Entity]` can be produced by the compiler.

Usage:

```
entities.spawnEntity[Bird]
```

Using something like `Rabbit( /* params here * /)` will not work though, because that is an instance, and not a class.

Comment: Neat, got it working! I guess I was asking about the wrong thing though. Let's say Entity is an object, not a class. How would you go about that, then? The usage would be entities.spawnEntity(Bird). Ideally I could also pass arguments as well. I'll edit my question to reflect new understanding.